# Comparing the rates of Poisson distribution using Bayesian inference

Tags: probability, inference, prior, poisson-binomial-distribution, bayes-factors

In the 'Theory of Probability' book by Sir Harold Jeffreys, (5.15), the form of the Bayes Factors that he derives for the comparison of Poisson rates is the same as that of Binomial rates. But I did not understand what priors he uses for the rate parameter and also for what conditions(ranges) of the rate parameters of the Poisson processes and other assumptions that he uses to get this result.

In 5.14, he says,

> the discrepancy in the results should persist when y and y' are very large

Could someone please help me in understanding this result?